# How can I add line break into text that I am creating with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create text output from an xml file using xslt.
 
It is actually an xslt that creates SQL code.  Here is a part that outputs CREATE TABLE statements:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[<xsl:value-of select="@PhysicalName"/>] (
  <xsl:for-each select="EntityAttributes/EntityAttribute">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Attributes/Attribute[@AttributeID = current()/@EntityAttributeID]"/> ...
  </xsl:for-each>)
```

I want to have a line break after the "(" in the first line but cannot manage to find out how to do so.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you put

```
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

in your XSLT it will give a line break. It is not clear where you wish to put this. I am guessing you want:

```
<xsl:text>CREATE TABLE dbo.[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@PhysicalName"/><xsl:text>] (
</xsl:text>
```

In general you should always wrap text output in  ... it looks slightly horrid in the XSL but it preserves the spacing. Note that you can break the lines in the XSLT without affecting the result - e.g.

```
<xsl:text>CREATE TABLE dbo.[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@PhysicalName"/>
<xsl:text>] (&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

and yes, I agree about the explicit line break character. As you can see the XSLT is not very readable but it gets the right answer

Comment: You wrote *"As you can see the XSLT is not very readable"*. That's very subjective. I consider that with `xsl:text` the **stylesheet become very readable**. Maybe you want to say that the **output becomes less... inferable**.

Comment: I've seen some people define an entity &newline that expands to <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>. But that only makes the code more readable to someone who is familiar with the conventions it is using, so I'm not sure I would recommend it.

Answer (score 37):

As for line breaks, I myself prefer more explicit/readable way.

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Much better than empty elements in my opinion. +1

Comment: +1 Correct suggestion. Besides that not written convention is to use uppercase for hexadecimal character references, like in the specs: `#xA`. But they are case insensitive anyway.

Comment: Great answer @Flack - I still find using the XML entity a little unreadable so prefer to wrap it in a template as follows: <xsl:template name="lineFeed">
 <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:template> then reference the template using <xsl:call-template name="lineFeed"/>

Answer (score -2):

use  tags it's easy

```
Example:
<div>TOTAL STAR POINTS EARNED </div>
<div>TOTAL STAR POINTS REDEEMED </div>
<div>BALANCE STAR POINTS AVAILABLE </div>
```

output:

```
TOTAL STAR POINTS EARNED 
TOTAL STAR POINTS REDEEMED 
BALANCE STAR POINTS AVAILABLE
```

Comment: If you had read the question more carefully, you would have seen that the output is not HTML.